# How can I create a Date object with a specific format

Tags: java, date, java.util.date

```
String testDateString = "02/04/2014";
DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy"); 

Date d1 = df.parse(testDateString);
String date = df.format(d1);
```

Output String:

> 02/04/2014

Now I need the Date `d1` formatted in the same way (*"02/04/2014"*).

Comment: what do you want in output? long value?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Convert string to Date in java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9945072/convert-string-to-date-in-java)

Comment: Please describe what is the result string you expect/want to get.

Answer (score 5):

If you want a date object that will always print your desired format, you have to create an own subclass of class `Date` and override `toString` there.

```
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Date;

public class MyDate extends Date {
    private final SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");

    public MyDate() { }

    public MyDate(Date source) {
        super(source.getTime());
    }

    // ...

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return dateFormat.format(this);
    }
}
```

Now you can create this class like you did with `Date` before and you don't need to create the `SimpleDateFormat` every time.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    MyDate date = new MyDate();
    System.out.println(date);
}
```

The output is `23/08/2014`.

This is the updated code you posted in your question:

```
String testDateString = "02/04/2014";
DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy"); 

MyDate d1 = new MyDate(df.parse(testDateString));
System.out.println(d1);
```

Note that you don't have to call `df.format(d1)` anymore, `d1.toString()` will return the date as the formated string.

Answer (score 2):

Try like this:

```
    SimpleDateFormat sdf =  new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");

    Date d= new Date(); //Get system date

    //Convert Date object to string
    String strDate = sdf.format(d);

    //Convert a String to Date
    d  = sdf.parse("02/04/2014");
```

Hope this may help you!

Comment: Where is the difference between your code and the code posted by OP?

Comment: And why do you cast the result of `parse` to Date? It returns a Date object.

Comment: I dont want this Wed Apr 02 00:00:00 GMT 2014 output. I need 02/04/2014

Comment: @user2243468 and you get this using your code you've posted. There is the problem now? That `date2` (or your `d1`) won't print your desired format natively? For that you have to create your own class `MyDate` that will extend the `Date` class and there you override the `toString` method. In there you can format your output how you want.