# How to set date format of a date into Date but not String?

Tags: java, string, date, date-format

Here's what I need to do :

I want to change the date2 into a Date but not String.

```
 Date date = new Date();
 DateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat ("yyyy/MM/dd",Locale.ENGLISH);
 String date2 = format.format(date);
```

It does not allow me to save date2 as a Date. Someone please help me. Thanks

Comment: you have to use parse method. and then give it string formatted date. like this `format.parse("2014/12/12");`

Comment: [This answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25460965/how-to-convert-string-to-date-format-in-android/25461759#25461759) might help you here.

Comment: Why was the accepted answer accepted? It has nothing to do with the question. The correct answer is [the one by Jesper](http://stackoverflow.com/a/27482690/642706) explaining that the Question is nonsense due to a lack of understanding the data types.

Comment: Well, just because that one helps me and I don't understand the other one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Date;

String your_date = "2014-12-15 00:00:00.0";
DateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat ("yyyy/MM/dd",Locale.ENGLISH);
Date new_date = format.parse(your_date);
System.out.println(new_date);
```

Answer (score 3):

`java.util.Date` objects do not have a format. They just represent a date value. You cannot "set the format of a `Date` object" because a `Date` object can't store this information.

What you are asking ("how do I set the format of a `Date` object") is not possible, because that's not how `Date` objects work.

What you should do instead is just work with the `Date` object and at the point where it needs to be displayed, you convert it to a `String` in the desired format using a `SimpleDateFormat` object.

Comment: because I need my parameter requires a date and I need to format the date to save into my database with the selected format. Or should I change the date to a string  instead in the entity.

Comment: @user3900009 This answer is correct. Your database should be using a date-time data type, probably TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE. Your Java code should use date-time data types. No Strings involved until you want to display the date-time values to the user or your logs. Search StackOverflow for *thousands* of examples. Indeed, always search before posting.