# How to get date from room database

Tags: android, sqlite, android-sqlite, android-room, android-database

I use `room database` and want to save date in database.

I want to save date with this format `"dd/MM/yy"` to database.

So i create `DateConverter` class to written from/into the database.

Now i can save date with my favorite format into the database but i can't get date from database with my favorite format and when i get the date gives me all info of Date(date , time ,day).

I can use `toTimestamp` method from `DateConverter` but i think is not good idea.

I want to know is there a way to get date directly without using `DateConverter.toTimestamp`.

```
@Entity(tableName = "notes")
public class NoteEntity {
    @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true)
    private int id;
    private Date date;
    private String text;

    @Ignore
    public NoteEntity() {
    }

    public NoteEntity(int id, Date date, String text) {
        this.id = id;
        this.date = date;
        this.text = text;
    }}

    @Ignore
    public NoteEntity(Date date, String text) {
        this.date = date;
        this.text = text;
    }

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public Date getDate() {
        return date;
    }

    public void setDate(Date date) {
        this.date = date;
    }

    public String getText() {
        return text;
    }

    public void setText(String text) {
        this.text = text;
    }
```

**DateConverter**

```
public class DateConverter {

   @TypeConverter
    public static Date toDate(String stringdate){
        return stringdate == null ? null : new Date(stringdate);
    }

    @TypeConverter
    public static String toTimestamp(Date date){
        SimpleDateFormat dateTimeFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yy");
        return dateTimeFormat.format(date);
    }
}
```

**Dao**

```
@Dao
public interface NoteDao {

    @Insert(onConflict = OnConflictStrategy.REPLACE)
    void insertAll(List<NoteEntity> noteEntity);

    @Query("SELECT * FROM notes")
    List<NoteEntity> loadAllNotes();
}
```

**Sample Data**

```
public static List<NoteEntity> getNotes() {
    List<NoteEntity> notes = new ArrayList<>();
    notes.add(new NoteEntity(new Date(2019,8,5), SAMPLE_TEXT_1));
    .
    .
    .
    return notes;
}
```

**Main**

```
AppDatabase appDatabase = AppDatabase.getInstance(context);

appDatabase.noteDao().insertAll(getNotes());

List<NoteEntity> notesData = new ArrayList<>();
notesData = appDatabase.noteDao().loadAllNotes();
        Log.i("TestOutput1", String.valueOf(notesData.get(0).getDate()));
        Log.i("TestOutput2", DateConverter.toTimestamp(notesData .get(0).getDate()));
```

**LogCat**

```
I/TestOutput1: Mon Aug 05 00:00:00 GMT+04:30 2019
I/TestOutput2: 05/08/19
```

Comment: You'll need to use `SimpleDateFormat` to convert your desired format from your input date in your `@TypeConverter` method so that your desired date would be saved.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/27482709/7316510 this link might help you to achieve your requirement.

Answer (score 2):

Save it as a string

```js
val dateFormat : DateFormat = SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss'Z'") 
try {  
    val date: Date = Date(); 
    val dateTime = dateFormat.format(date)
    println("Current Date Time : " + dateTime)
} catch (e:ParseException ) {
    println(e)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should convert from Date to String and from String (primitive) to Date. I had changed it to String and it compiled.

```
public class DateConverter {

  public static Date toDate(String stringdate){
     return timestamp == null ? null : new Date(stringdate);
  }

  public static String toTimestamp(Date date){
      SimpleDateFormat dateTimeFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yy");        
      return dateTimeFormat.format(date);
  }
}
```

Comment: i replaced your method's and problem is still . I think now `toTimestamp` save correctly format in db but `toDate` return result with a new Date() again and in output so still has hour and day.

Comment: You need to store converted String into a database, I already did the same code & it works for me.

Comment: i checked database values and everythings is correct but i don't know how to get date from database correctly . I just can get correct format with use `toTimestamp ` again `Log.i("TEST", DateConverter.toTimestamp(test.get(0).getDate()));`but i don't know my way is true or not

Comment: You need to change variable private Date date to private String date

Comment: If i do this so actually i don't need DateConverter.

Comment: so is it useful?