# how to store date in particular format if input itself is a date?

Tags: java

I am trying to store the expiry date in exp. The format I want to store it is "yyyy-MM-dd".I tried using SimpleDateFormat and than tried to format to get a string and than parse the string as follows:

```
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
Date exp = sdf.parse(sdf.format(c.getTime()));
```

But result is I don't get date saved in exp as yyyy-MM-dd.
I want to know given a date in particular format How do I convert it in other date format if the input itself is a date in one format and output is date is other format. I have used GregorianCalendar to getTime.

The format of manufacturing date is"yyyy-MM-dd";
I want the date to be stored in same format in exp;

```
public void calculateExpiryDate(List <Item> items) {
    Iterator <Item> itr = items.iterator();

    while (itr.hasNext()) {
        Item i = itr.next();
        Date md = i.getManufacturingDate();
        int ubm = i.getUseBeforeMonths();

        Calendar c = new GregorianCalendar();
        c.setTime(md);
        //System.out.println(c);
        c.add(Calendar.MONTH, ubm);

        Date exp = c.getTime();
        i.setExpiryDate(exp);
        SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
        System.out.println(md + " " + ubm + " " + sdf.format(exp) + "  " + " " + i.getId());
    }
}
```

here is my code for Items:

```
public class Item implements Comparable<Item>{
    private int id;
    private String description;
    private float weight;
    private float price;
    private Date manufacturingDate;
    private int useBeforeMonths;
    private Date   expiryDate;


    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }
    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }
    public String getDescription() {
        return description;
    }
    public void setDescription(String description) {
        this.description = description;
    }
    public float getWeight() {
        return weight;
    }
    public void setWeight(float weight) {
        this.weight = weight;
    }
    public float getPrice() {
        return price;
    }
    public void setPrice(float price) {
        this.price = price;
    }
    public Date getManufacturingDate() {
        return manufacturingDate;
    }
    public void setManufacturingDate(Date manufacturingDate) {
        this.manufacturingDate = manufacturingDate;
    }
    public int getUseBeforeMonths() {
        return useBeforeMonths;
    }
    public void setUseBeforeMonths(int useBeforeMonths) {
        this.useBeforeMonths = useBeforeMonths;
    }

    public void setExpiryDate(Date expiryDate) {
        this.expiryDate = expiryDate;
    }
    public Date getExpiryDate() {
        return expiryDate;
    }
    @Override
    public int compareTo(Item arg0)
    {
        Date exp1=getExpiryDate();
        Date exp2=arg0.getExpiryDate();
        if(exp1.getYear()==exp2.getYear())
        {
            if(exp1.getMonth()==exp2.getMonth())
            {
                return exp2.getDate()-exp1.getDate();
            }
            else
                return exp2.getMonth()-exp1.getMonth();
        }
        return exp2.getYear()-exp1.getYear();
    }   

}
```

Comment: What do you exactly mean with "I want to store"? Where do you want to store this? In a java variable? On disk?

Comment: you have to add another date formatter to get the format that you want

Comment: exp variable is of type: Date and when you do sdf.format(exp), nothing happens to exp. sdf.format(exp) actually formats and returns StringBuffer which you can use.

Comment: @WimDeblauwe I want to store in java variable exp. So when setExpiry is called the instance variable expiry date in Item class of type date should be assigned value of exp in the form"yyyy-MM-dd"

Comment: @Spartan can you provide an example.

Comment: Maybe someone should tell you, that a `Date` doesn't has any format (except the one in the `toString` implementation) ...

Comment: @Tom I used  ' SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
Date exp = sdf.parse("2015-10-10");  ' n try to print exp I get 2015-10-10.What I want is the Date to be in format 2015-01-09 and if Input is Fri Jan 09 00:00:00 IST 2015. Both stored in type date

Comment: Can you provide the code of `Item` ?

Comment: That still doesn't change the fact, that `Date` doesn't has any format. You can get a formatted String out of that date, but the Date object itself remains unformatted.

Comment: @Spotted I have added code for Items.

Comment: @Tom do you mean I have to override toString in date ?

Comment: You can't do that, since `Date` cannot be changed. But you can create your own subclass of `Date` and override it there. Check the answer provided by @Spotted for an example.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understand correctly...

You want, inside `setExpiryDate` get the `date` as a `String` into the format `"yyyy-MM-dd"`. And as a constraint, the `Item.setExpiryDate` doesn't want to care about any `SimpleDateFormat`.

A solution is to use a kind of [decorator pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decorator_pattern) to redefine the string representation of a date.

```
public final class ExpirationDate extends Date {
    private final SimpleDateFormat formatter;

    public ExpirationDate(Date origin) {
        super(origin.getTime());
        this.formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
    }

    @Override
    public final String toString() {
        return formatter.format(this);
    }
}
```

And wrap your `Date` in a `ExpirationDate` every time you need this kind of representation:

```
Date exp = c.getTime();
i.setExpiryDate(new ExpirationDate(exp));
```

Comment: Reminds me of my own [Version of this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25460965/how-to-convert-string-to-date-format-in-android/25461759#25461759) :D. So this is a good way to handle this situation :).

Comment: @Spotted thanks a ton :) worked amazingly well for me

Answer (score 0):

Try this -

```
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.GregorianCalendar;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.text.DateFormat;
import java.util.Calendar;

public class Temp {
  public static void main(String args[]) {
      String startDateString = "2012-03-12";
      DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
      Date startDate;
      try{
          startDate = df.parse(startDateString);

          Calendar c= new GregorianCalendar();
          c.setTime(startDate);
          c.add(Calendar.MONTH, 3);
          Date exp=c.getTime();
          SimpleDateFormat sdf=new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
          String expDate = sdf.format(exp).toString();
          System.out.println(expDate);
      }catch(Exception e){
      }
  }//Body
}
```

Comment: expDate is of type string. I want the final output itself as Date and not string.

Comment: but it is not of the form I want it as, when I try to print it its not getting printed as yyyy-MM-dd. When I do the same with Manufacturind date that is md it gets printed as yyyy-MM-dd.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if you manufacturing date is displayed in SDF format you mentioned. The SDF format can be used for storing date in String format

```
Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
    Date md = new Date();
    int ubm = 4;
    //System.out.println(c);
    c.setTime(md);
    c.add(Calendar.MONTH, ubm);

    Date exp = c.getTime();
    //i.setExpiryDate(exp);
    SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
    String strExpiry =  sdf.format(exp);
    System.out.println("Expiry Date in String format " + strExpiry );
    Date dtExpiry = sdf.parse(strExpiry);
    System.out.println("Expiry Date in Date format " + dtExpiry);
```

where as if converted to Date the result will be again the complete Date output as shown below

> Expiry Date in String format 2016-02-01
>   Expiry Date in Date format Mon Feb 01 00:00:00 IST 2016

Comment: I want output the Date to be in format 2015-01-09 and if Input is Fri Jan 09 00:00:00 IST 2015. Both stored in type date

Comment: Looking at the Date class toString() implementation, don't think it will print the date in the format you expect.