# date is not showing as i customize it in JDateChooser using java

Tags: java

It was working before on my other computer but now the date is not changing.
I get the date from `JDateChooser`:

```java
if(txt_date_creation.getDate()!=null){
    q.setDate("dc",txt_date_creation.getDate());
}
```

And this is the format that I'm using:

> dd/MM/yyyy

And the output is:

```
Tue Apr 13 00:00:00 BST 2021
```

Comment: If you can find a date picker that supports java.time, the modern Java date and time API, then discard the `Date` class completely. It is poorly designed and long outdated. BTW the output you get comes from `Date.toString()`.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [display Java.util.Date in a specific format](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6262310/display-java-util-date-in-a-specific-format). Does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18628059/change-the-format-of-date-java)? [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35913647/format-a-date-and-returning-a-date-not-a-string)? [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50485203/return-date-type-with-format-in-java)?

Comment: Is `txt_date_creation` your `JDateChooser`?

Comment: i dont know im gonna try it

Comment: yes txt_date_chooser is my jdatechooser

Comment: and i try to use simplleDateformat and it give's me the same output,