# How to convert String to LocalDate

Tags: java, localdate, datetimeformatter

```
String date = "1992-07-25";

LocalDate dt = LocalDate.parse(date);

System.out.println(dt) // 1992-07-25 ( output )

DateTimeFormatter f =  DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("d/MM/yyyy");

String s1 = f.format(dt); 

System.out.println(s1) // 25/07/1992 ( output in string format )
```

**I want this (String) s1 to convert into LocalDate of pattern (LocalDate - dd/MM/yyy)**

**Output - 25/07/1992 should be LocalDate Type, not String**

Comment: Recommend you to check Basil Bourque's answer in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35913647/format-a-date-and-returning-a-date-not-a-string

Comment: Your Question makes no sense. You successfully parsed input text of standard ISO 8601 format to produce a `LocalDate` object. You then defined and used a formatter of a custom format to produce another  string representing the value contained within that `LocalDate` object. All went well. What is your problem/question?

Comment: Duplicate or repost of: [Change string to LocalDate with specific format in JAVA](https://stackoverflow.com/q/68148621/642706)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you are printing **LocalDate** instance, it is actually calling **toString()** method of **LocalDate** class. And according to [javadoc 11](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/LocalDate.html#toString()), this method

```
Outputs this date as a String, such as 2007-12-03.
The output will be in the ISO-8601 format uuuu-MM-dd.
```

So you are seeing, it will always print in **uuuu-MM-dd** format.

Think **LocalDate** as a **DATE** just, from where you can get the info of that particular date. When you are printing LocalDate itself, it has no meaning actually. If you need to show the date in any particular format, convert it into String, which you can do already.