# Formatting Calendar

Tags: java, calendar

I need to formatt Calendar to get just the Date DD/MM/YY but no converted into String, i need it into Date dataType.

```
SimpleDateFormat simpleDate = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/M/yy");
Calendar cal2 = new GregorianCalendar(simpleDate);
 dateFormat.format(date); //Here i need to store the Date (dd/M/yy) into a Date kin of variable. (NO STRING)
```

Thus, when i need to update Calendar, into the Date result will reflect the changes.

Comment: Read this [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25460965/how-can-i-create-a-date-object-with-a-specific-format), understand its answer and then you'll know how to achieve the same for your `Calendar` sub-class.

Answer (score -1):

I do not know if this is close enough if someone with more experience can check this over that would be nice!

To truncate a combined "date and time" `java.util.Date` to just the date component, leaving it effectively at midnight

```
public static Date truncateTime (Date date) {
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
cal.setTime( date);
cal.set( Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 0);
cal.set( Calendar.MINUTE, 0);
cal.set( Calendar.SECOND, 0);
cal.set( Calendar.MILLISECOND, 0);
return cal.getTime();
```

}

Answer (score -1):

## No such thing as formatted date

A date-time value stored in a date-time class **has no format**.

A date-time object can *generate* a String object whose text is in a certain format to represent the date-time’s value. But the String and the date-time are separate and distinct from one another.

## java.time

The [`LocalDate`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalDate.html) class represents a date-only value, without time-of-day and without time zone.

A time zone is crucial in determining a `LocalDate`. For any given moment, the date varies around the globe by time zone. For example, a few minutes after midnight is still “yesterday” in Montréal.

```
ZoneId zoneId = ZoneId.of( "America/Montreal" );
LocalDate today = LocalDate.now( zoneId );
```

Avoid using the troublesome old date-time classes such as java.util.Date and java.util.Calendar. Use only java.time classes.

## Convert from `GregorianCalendar`

If you have a `GregorianCalendar` object, convert to a `ZonedDateTime` by calling the new method added to the old class, [`toZonedDateTime`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/GregorianCalendar.html#toZonedDateTime--).

```
ZonedDateTime zdt = myGregCal.toZonedDateTime();
```

From there get a `LocalDate`. The ZonedDateTime object’s own assigned time zone is used to determine that date.

```
LocalDate localDate = zdt.toLocalDate();
```

## Convert from `java.util.Date`

If you have a `java.util.Date` object, convert to an `Instant`. This class represents a moment on the timeline in UTC.

```
Instant instant = myUtilDate.toInstant();
```

Apply a time zone to get a `ZonedDateTime`. Then obtain a `LocalDate` as we saw above.

```
ZoneId zoneId = ZoneId.of( "America/Montreal" );
ZonedDateTime zdt = ZonedDateTime.ofInstant( instant , zoneId );
LocalDate localDate = zdt.toLocalDate();
```

## Immutable objects

The java.time classes follow the [Immutable Objects](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Immutable_object) design. Rather than alter (“mutate”) the value or attributes of a java.time object, a new java.time object is instantiated based on the attributes of the original object.

## Generate String

When you want to generate a String to represent the `LocalDate` value, define a formatting pattern.

```
DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern( "dd/M/yy" );
String output = localDate.format( formatter );
```

By the way, I strongly advise against the use of two-digit years. The ambiguity raised and issues involved with parsing are not worth the savings of two characters.

Comment: Dear Down-Voter: please leave a criticism along with your vote.

Comment: What the Asker is asking is just for format the date, what you are posting is a complete cathedra ..