# Convert 24-hour String to DateTime

Tags: c#, string, datetime, uwp

I have a string containing the date and time

```
string startDate = "30-09-2022 09:00:00";
DateTime startdate = DateTime.ParseExact(startDate, 
                                        "dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss", 
                                        CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

I want to convert to `DateTime`, but it doesn't work and the error message is:

> System.FormatException: String '30-09-2022 09:00:00' was not
> recognized as a valid DateTime

How to solve it?

Note: the string is in 24-hour format

Comment: lets take a closer look at `30-09-2022` and `dd/MM/yyyy` parts

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601?wprov=sfla1

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Convert string to Date in java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9945072/convert-string-to-date-in-java)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The "Exact" in `ParseExact()` means it... your format string much match the data **perfectly**. For example, you can't use `/` if the data has `-`.

```
DateTime startdate = DateTime.ParseExact(startDate, "dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm:ss", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

The exception is `/` is actually a special [placeholder for the date separator defined in the current culture](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/custom-date-and-time-format-strings#dateSeparator). Here we're using the invariant culture, so this could work if and only if `-` is also set as the date separator for that culture (hint: it's not).

Answer (score 0):

Your date string has '-' between the date elements and your format string has '/' slashes.  This is not an exact parse.

```
string startDate = "30-09-2022 09:00:00";
DateTime startdate = DateTime.ParseExact(startDate, "dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm:ss", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

or

```
string startDate = "30/09/2022 09:00:00";
DateTime startdate = DateTime.ParseExact(startDate, "dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```